# C++ Dynamic Programming: error in traversing the grid

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here's a [question 8](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2018_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_8) from [2018 AIME Paper](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2018_AIME_II_Problems) : A frog is positioned at the origin of the coordinate plane. From the point `(x, y)`, the frog can jump to any of the points `(x + 1, y)`, `(x + 2, y)`, `(x, y + 1)`, or `(x, y + 2)`. Find the number of distinct sequences of jumps in which the frog begins at `(0, 0)` and ends at `(x, y)`.

It felt that it can be solved using dynamic programming but my code seems to have an error which I cannot debug. This is how I approached the problem:

If `f[i][j]` denotes the number of ways to reach grid-point `(i, j)` from `(0, 0)` then

```
f[i][j] = f[i - 1][j] + f[i - 2][j] + f[j - 1][i] + f[j - 2][i]
```

and we have to assign values of `f[][]` for the base cases..

I don't think there's an issue with the logic. But the outputs are terrible. 
Here's my code : https://ideone.com/lhhMUL

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n, x, y;
    cin >> n >> x >> y;
    int f[n][n];
    f[0][1] = f[1][0] = 1;
    f[0][2] = f[2][0] = 2;
    f[1][2] = f[2][1] = 5;

    for (int i = 2; i <= x - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= y - 1; j++) {
            f[i][j] = f[i - 1][j]
                      + f[i - 2][j]
                      + f[j - 1][i]
                      + f[j - 2][i];
        }
    }
    cout << f[y][x];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two bugs I see are

1. j and i are reversed in your recursion equation
2. Initial values of f (for example f[3][1] ) are never calculated. They are just random values of what was in memory when the arrays were allocated.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 

{
    int n,x,y; cin>>n>>x>>y;
    int f[n][n];
    f[0][0]=1;
    f[1][0]=1;
    f[0][1]=1;
    f[1][1]=2;   

    for(int i = 2; i <= x; i ++ ) {
        f[i][0] = f[i-1][0] + f[i-2][0];
    }
    for(int i = 2; i <= x; i ++ ) {
        f[i][1] = f[i-1][1] + f[i-2][1] + f[i][0];
    }
    for(int j = 2; j <= y; j ++ ) {
        f[0][j] = f[0][j-1] + f[0][j-2];
    }
    for(int j = 2; j <= y; j ++ ) {
        f[1][j] = f[1][j-1] + f[1][j-2] + f[0][j];
    }

    for (int i=2; i<=x; i++)
        for (int j=2; j<=y; j++) {
            f[i][j]=f[i-1][j]+f[i-2][j]+f[i][j-1]+f[i][j-2];
            // cout << i << " " << j << " " << f[i][j] << endl;
        }

    cout<< f[x][y];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand that i,j were reversed in my code. To compensate that, note that I had reversed y,x at the end. (cout<<f[y][x] is what I had printed). Now, I understand your second point, that values with either of i,j equal to 1 or 0 are not printed and they've to be taken care of. But anyway, your code doesn't seem to execute properly either. Right?

Comment: Explicitly announcing the language before a code block fixes the code-after-list problem. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109

Comment: @Mathejunior, if you are continuing to use the switched i and j with the new boundary conditions, then you will still have problems. I don't know if you are or not. Why do you think my code does not execute properly? Please show the input/output.  Thanks!

Comment: @mwistrom Please have a look here : https://ideone.com/UtK3h7 the answer that's supposed to print is the number of ways to travel from (0,0) to (3,3) right? But that's not so big a number. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Mathejunior Yep. I had bugs too! The endpoints in all the for loops were wrong. Fixed and edited.

Comment: Oops, we missed that. Yeah, thank you for helping me debug the code. :)